# Different validation on multiple models in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

If I have a view model looking something like this:

```
    public class FlightViewModel {
    public BookingFlight BookingFlight { get; set; } // contains list of FlightPassengers
    public FlightPassenger AddedPassenger { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view that displays the editor for both models along with a webgrid outputting the list of FlightPassengers contained in BookingFlight, similar to this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <legend>Flight Booking</legend>
        @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEditBookingFlight")
        @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEditPassenger")
        @grid.GetHtml()
        <p>
            <button name="button" value="addPassenger">Add New Passenger</button>
            <button name="button" value="submitBooking">Submit Booking</button>
        </p>
}
```

My issue is: both buttons cause require both the BookingFlight and FlightPassenger parts to be correctly validated. In an ideal scenario a user could add a valid passenger without any flight info being valid.

So what's the best way to only validate parts of a viewmodel? Or am I going about this all the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a single view model class, you could implement `IValidatableObject` and its `Validate` method

```
public class FlightViewModel : IValidatableObject {
    public BookingFlight bookingFlight { get; set; } // contains list of FlightPassengers
    public FlightPassenger addedPassenger { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(
        ValidationContext validationContext) {

        // .IsValid properties are made up
        if (!bookingFlight.IsValid && !addedPassenger.IsValid)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Something blew up", new string[] { "addedPassenger", "bookingFlight" });

        // implement other validation and yield additional
        // ValidationResult's as needed
    }
}
```

So, if the `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>` returned has .Count > 0, then the view model will not validate.

Keep in mind, if you're using Validation Messages in your view, I think you might need the Validation *Summary* for any `yield`'ed `ValidationResult`'s added.